# findOne by Id issue in Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-documentdb

I have a very strange issue.

See the code below

```
const pqr = new ObjectId(smsId);
console.log('pqr', pqr)
docDB.collection(constants.prefix.mongo.COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION)
  .findOne(({ "_id": pqr }, (err, notificationDetails) => {
    console.log('smsId 3', smsId)
    console.log('notificationDetails', notificationDetails) })
```

below is output

```
pqr 60986d6210a23dcec4b01e99 // see here
smsId 3 60986d6210a23dcec4b01e99
notificationDetails {
  _id: 60986b7e10a23dcec4b01e96, // and here
  highPriority: true,.....
```

I am getting different _id than that of the searched one.

the database is amazon documentDB.
client is nodejs client.

what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const pqr = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(smsId);
```

Try this once. If you are using Mongoose library.

If you are using Mongodb Library then try this.

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
const pqr = ObjectId(smsId);
```